# What is pip in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I have installed  `Python 3.4.1` in windows desktop, but i don't have pip. I am trying to install a module from `https://www.reportlab.com/reportlabplus/installation/` it shows `pip install rlextra -i https://www.reportlab.com/pypi/`.  And then if I execute the reported command, it shows the following

```
C:\Python34>pip install rlextra -i https://www.reportlab.com/pypi/
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Edit: This question is not about how to  install pip, instead why you need pip ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The pip command is a tool for installing and managing Python packages, such as
those found in the Python Package Index.

It's a replacement for easy_install.

https://github.com/pypa/pip

Using PIP, You can install the module. It will install the dependency also.

Comment: Thanks for answer "managing Python packages". these words clarify lot. Again thanks  for your time.

Answer (score 5):

Pip is a package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python. 
You have to download PIP.then you can use pip to install packages.
download pip from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment, so take a look at this link

[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

you can think of pip as a "package" manager, you use it to install certain libraries or packages to your python installation.