# Django-allauth best practices

Tags: django, authentication, virtualenv, django-allauth

Just trying to look for some help on best practices for using `django-allauth` and implementing it into a project.

First, where should `Django-allauth` be located? I have it in my virtual environment, which is outside of my Django project. Should I create an app and then install it into that app (which would be located in the project) or is it perfectly fine where it is now? I am trying to make it easier for implementing updates or making changes, etc.

Second, where should the virtual environment be located? As previously stated, I have it located outside of the Django project folder. Is that fine and makes sense?

Lastly, is there anyway to change the table names for Django-allauth? Would it make sense to change the default on how Django names tables in a database?

Answer (score 1):

External dependencies such as `django-allauth` are normally added to your package manager's requirement file. For example, for a [`pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354399/) based deployment setup it would typically be a line in a file named `requirements.txt`:

```
django~=4.2
django-allauth~=0.58
# ... other dependencies
```

Then you set must set up a manual or automated deployment process where you install/update all dependencies before each deployment. Again, for a `pip` based deployment process that might be as simple as the following:

```
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

Your virtual environment can be anywhere you want. Creating it in the project folder is not the worst idea, but there are both [pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936425/) for either approach.

Regarding your last question, why do you want to change the table names in the first place?